# how can i use RestApi to update deployment in k8s?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, postman

I want to use the RestApi to update the deployment.
and I test it with postman, but always got 415 back.

---

the info is as follows:

**type:**
PATCH

**url:** https://k8sClusterUrl:6443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/ns/deployments/peer0

**header:**

```
Authorization: bearer token  
Content-Type:application/json
```

**body:**

```
{
    "kind": "Deployment",
    "spec":
    {
        "template":
        {
            "spec":
            {
                "containers":[
                    {
                        "$setElementOrder/volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/host/var/run/"},{"mountPath":"/mnt"}],
                        "name":"peer0",
                        "image":"hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**response:**

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "the server responded with the status code 415 but did not return more information",
    "details": {},
    "code": 415
}
```

---

I have muti-containers in this pod, and only want to apply for the specific container: `peer0`.
Any different for the `$setElementOrder` var?

Answer (score 2):

`415` is invalid media type.

In this case, you should be setting the media type as `application/json+patch+json` (you can see this in the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/federation/extensions/v1beta1/operations/))

Comment: but i got another error after changing the Content-Type to application/json-patch+json
 :             
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type jsonpatch.Patch",
    "code": 500
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try using body and using Content-Type to application/json-patch+json, method PATCH:

```
[{
"op" : "replace",
"path" : "/spec/template/spec/container/0/$setElementOrder/volumeMounts",
"value" : "<value you want to replace>"
}]
```